# File upload working in emulator, but not in device

Tags: android, wcf

I am uploading a image file to my live server(WCF Service) using multi-part and stream.
Image size is 500-700KB,when i use real camera.From emulator it successfully upload sample but when i install it to my Sony Ericsson Arc S, application not upload any image. There are code for checking status code but nothing happen, no error, no exception, no server response.In my phone i am using mobile data connectivity(provider Grammen Phone,GSM, Bangladesh). Don't understand what's the problem. Can any body help me?

andriod code:

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/uploadImage");
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File imageFile = new File(dir, getImagepath(directoryName, false));     
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(imageFile, "image/jpeg"));
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    final int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            });
                    } else {
                         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Failed,status:"+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                } else {
                     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File dont't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                }
```

**Update:**
I added a log writer in the exception catch block which generated a log file."Connection to x.x.x.x:xxxx refused", so it is clear that it is getting a exception and it is from server side.But still don't know what's the problem.

**Update:**
At last, I got the problem!It was my "multipart parser" on server side and i used wrong ServiceURi in android code .You have to be careful to choose the parser for your need.I did few modification to my parser file,and it works! But still need to modify the parser,because lots of other staffs need to be incorporated.Anyway, thanks for your effort! Useful link:http://www.ideatoappster.com/android-to-wcf-streaming-multi-part-binary-images/

Comment: Via android ConnectivityManager . First check connection ok before upload.  connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  netInfo = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

Answer (score 0):

us this method to convert Uri path to String

```
public String getImagepath(Uri uri) {
        String[] largeFileProjection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };
        String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
        Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
        String largeImagePath = "";
        try {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            largeImagePath = myCursor
                    .getString(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
        } finally {
            myCursor.close();
        }
        return largeImagePath;
    }



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode) {
                 case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                   Uri  mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();

                Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data");
                         }
}
```

For getting String path of this Uri onActivityResult

call this getImagepath(mImageCaptureUri )

May be problem will be getting the capture image path.
So try this getImagepath() function.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, tried it earlier , you will get very low quality image from get("data") and i get the image when uploading, no problem with that issue except no response from server.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a firewall issue on your server.  Connection refused means that you've reached the machine, but there was either no service running to accept the connection or it was blocked by a firewall.